# libcurl C not putting string quotes in boundary in Content-Type header for multipart case

Tags: libcurl

I am using libcurl in C, to implement HTTP interface in my application.

I have a requirement for MIME (multipart content) to be shared to other application.

But the other application is sending an 400 error because libcurl is not adding quotes around the boundary identifier in Content-Type header.

### What libcurl is sending:

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=------------------------d7faf74803c32e10

### What is required:

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="------------------------d7faf74803c32e10"

Though this is not a mandatory as per RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1.1), but its a recommend one.

Is there any way we can achieve through libcurl - C ? Pls help. Thanks is advance.

Comment: It's not possible to change with the API, you need to edit source code and recompile. I first wrote the support in curl for that feature based on [RFC 1867](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1867) and as you can see in there, all the examples do boundaries without quotes...

Comment: Let me try it out. Thanks for input.